# Session Datatable to database

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Hello I am trying something in which I am not really an expert and only have reached so far with great help.

I have a table and a form such as this

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXBhk.jpg

the table is populated by a datatable i stored in a session while the form is goes to a [httppost] method. my problem is when i click the save button the form data is being saved but not the table

my view looks like this

```
    @using cgs.Models;
@model ConfirmOrderCustomModel

@using System.Data;
@using System.Net;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditProduct";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/DashboardLayout.cshtml";
}

<div id="form-wrapper" class="page-wrapper">
    <div id="overview-row" class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Confirm Order</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="form-div" class="row edit-form">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmOrder", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @*@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <table id="calculate-table" class="rwd-table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Order Units</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Discount</th>
                            <th>Net</th>
                        </tr>
                        @{
                            if (Session["tblCart"] != null)
                            {
                                DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["tblCart"];

                                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        @foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                                        {
                                            <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                                        }
                                        <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="Remove(this)" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Orders.ShippingDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Shipping Date", @id = "lblShippingDate", @class = "label" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Orders.ShippingDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "date", @min = 0, @value = "", @placeholder = "Shipping Date", @name = "shippingDate", @id = "shippingDate", @required = "" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Orders.ShippingDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Orders.OrderTotal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Total", @id = "lblTotal", @class = "label" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Orders.OrderTotal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @min = 0, @value = "", @placeholder = "Total", @name = "total_price", @id = "total_price", @required = "" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Orders.OrderTotal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Orders.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Customer", @id = "lblCustomer", @class = "label" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Orders.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @min = 0, @value = "", @placeholder = "Customer", @name = "cust_name", @id = "cust_name", @required = "" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Orders.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Orders.CustomerPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "CustomerPhone", @id = "lblPhone", @class = "label" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Orders.CustomerPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @min = 0, @value = "", @placeholder = "Customer Phone", @name = "cust_phone", @id = "cust_phone", @required = "" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Orders.CustomerPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Orders.CustomerEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Email", @id = "lblEmail", @class = "label" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Orders.CustomerEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @min = 0, @value = "", @placeholder = "Email", @name = "cust_email", @id = "cust_email", @required = "" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Orders.CustomerEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Orders.DeliveryAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Delivery Address", @id = "lblAddress", @class = "label" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Orders.DeliveryAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @min = 0, @value = "", @placeholder = "Address", @name = "cust_address", @id = "cust_Address", @required = "" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Orders.DeliveryAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                    <button id="btnSave" name="action" value="confirm">Confirm Order</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var sum1 = 0;
            $("#calculate-table tr").not(':first').each(function () {
                sum1 += getnum($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
                function getnum(t) {
                    if (isNumeric(t)) {
                        return parseInt(t, 10);
                    }
                    return 0;
                    function isNumeric(n) {
                        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#total_price").val(sum1);
        }, 1000);
    });

    function Remove(button) {
        //Determine the reference of the Row using the Button.
        var row = $(button).closest("TR");
        var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {
            //Get the reference of the Table.
            var table = $("#calculate-table")[0];

            //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
            table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
        }
    };

    $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
        //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
        var orderProducts = new Array();
        $("#calculate-table tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var products = {};
            products.ProductID = row.find("td").eq(0).html();
            products.OrderUnits = row.find("td").eq(1).html();
            products.TotalSum = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
            products.DiscountVal = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
            products.NetSum = row.find("td").eq(4).html();
            orderProducts.push(products);
        });

        //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Product/ConfirmOrder",
            data: JSON.stringify(orderProducts),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                if (json.isRedirect) {
                    window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my actionresult like this

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ConfirmOrder(ConfirmOrderCustomModel model)
    {
        using(dbcontext = new CDBContext())
        {
            dbcontext.Orders.Add(new Model.Orders
            {
                ShippingDate = model.Orders.ShippingDate,
                OrderTotal = model.Orders.OrderTotal,
                CustomerName = model.Orders.CustomerName,
                CustomerPhone = model.Orders.CustomerPhone,
                CustomerEmail = model.Orders.CustomerEmail,
                DeliveryAddress = model.Orders.DeliveryAddress,
                OrderStatus = true
            });

            dbcontext.SaveChanges();

            int id = dbcontext.Orders.Max(odr => odr.ID);

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["tblCart"];
            List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>(dt.Select());

            foreach (var item in model.SalesModel)
            {
                dbcontext.OrderProducts.Add(new OrderProducts
                {
                    OrderUnits = item.OrderUnits,
                    TotalSum = item.TotalSum,
                    DiscountVal = item.DiscountVal,
                    NetSum = item.NetSum,
                    ProductID = item.ProductID,
                    OrderID = id
                });

                dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                redirectUrl = Url.Action("Dashboard", "Admin"),
                isRedirect = true
            });
        }


    }
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You create a `List<DataRow>` but you never use it. Are you expecting that to cause a database action? Additionally, using `Max()` to get the last order id is extremely fragile and unreliable.

Comment: @Crowcoder No that should line should be commented, I thought if could append the datatable to a list and the save the record for each row. I haven't figured a way out for it. Yes I have read that it can be prone to many vulnerabilities but I only have one user on my system and this is only workaround I guess until I can think of another way